# Why doesn't System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetData/SetData work?

Tags: .net, clipboard

I'm trying to add copy/paste to an application that edits items. Having a copy of the data for a set of selected items, should enable duplicating them or transporting them to another instance of the program. I've tried this:

```
const string MyClipboardFormat = "MyClipboardFormat"

private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  XmlDocument xdoc;
  //add data of selected items
  Clipboard.SetData(MyClipboardFormat,xdoc);
}

private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  XmlDocument xdoc = Clipboard.GetData(MyClipboardFormat) as XmlDocument;
  if (xdoc == null)
    throw new Exception("Clipboard does not contain MyClipboardFormat");
  //read item data from xdoc
}
```

I've googled but found only bits about using GetDataObject/SetDataObject, equivalent to what appears to be going on anyway, if I use reflector to look what GetData/SetData does.

Should I register the clipboard format string somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and to get it to work, I had to serialize the object before placing it on the clipboard and unserialize it after my call to Clipboard.GetData()

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your format. Use [`DataFormats.GeTFormat(MyClipboardFormat)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y444e6db(VS.80).aspx):

> Call this method with your own format
>   name to create a new Clipboard format
>   type. If the specified format does not
>   exist, this method will register the
>   name as a Clipboard format with the
>   Windows registry and get a unique
>   format identifier.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't help. I'm not even sure what to do with the 'format' returned here. GetData/SetData takes a string as format descriptor.